# Compiler warning when creating custom std stream implementation

Tags: c++, stream, compiler-warnings

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ application where I've created a custom streambuf and stream implementation. I've used an approach given by [Angelika Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/C++Report/IOStreamsDerivation/IOStreamsDerivation.html) for creating the stream detailed below:

```
class MyOutputStream_3 : private MyStreamBuf, public ostream {
public:
    MyOutputStream_3() : ostream((MyStreamBuf*) this), ios(0) {};
    virtual ~MyOutputStream_3() { sync(); }
    // ...
};
```

But, Visual Studio gives me a [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c594ae3%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

```
warning C4355: 'this' : used in base member initializer list
```

The code works fine, but I'm worried the compiler is informing me that what I've done either could break under some circumstances or may be non-portable.

Is this something I can ignore in this instance or what should I do to fix my issue?

Comment: _Never_ ignore warnings.

Comment: @Tomalak - Are you saying the code given is incorrect and that I should change it? If so, how? Or, are you saying I should keep that warning in mind because future changes could easily make the code incorrect?

Comment: As yet I have been unable to determine why the code may be incorrect/undefined. That does not mean that it isn't, and your compiler knows the language better than I do. Also there may be a "careful; your code is susceptible to turning badly wrong with the slightest change!" factor, which is also reason enough not to ignore warnings. They are not emitted just for fun! [I'm not saying that you _must_ change your code; just don't totally ignore the warning either. There's a middle ground somewhere. :)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++03 standard has this bit in a note for 12.6.2/7 "Initializaing bases and members":

> [Note: because the mem-initializer are evaluated in the scope of the constructor, the this pointer can be used in the expression-list of a mem-initializer to refer to the object being initialized. ]

I think the warning is issued becuase the object being referred to by the `this` pointer isn't fully initialized so there's some potential danger. As long as your base doesn't actually *use* the uninitialized parts of the object until after they're initialized, you should be fine.

As the MSDN docs for the warning (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c594ae3.aspx) mention:

> In effect, you've passed a pointer to an unconstructed object to another constructor. If those other constructors access any members or call member functions on this, the result will be undefined.

Comment: I'm sure I read once that converting `this` to a base type before the derived instance has been fully constructed is UB.

Comment: Incidentally, `[2003: 9.3.2]` doesn't seem to actually define the type of `this` in a member-initialiser.

Comment: @Tomalak:  Given `struct D : B { D() : B(this) { } };`, the `this` that appears in the initializer list is of type `D*`.  There is an example of this at C++03 §12.7/2, though this behavior is also implied by the manner in which virtual functions are dispatched.  (I admit that I don't know where the normative text is that specifies this.)

Comment: @Michael - so, if I understand you, I should be fine as long as the `std::ostream` doesn't rely on parts of `MyOutputStream` that aren't yet constructed. In this case, it only relies on `MyStreamBuf`, which is constructed first by virtue of its being the first in the inheritance list. So, the code above should be correct, right?

Comment: @James: I don't think there _is_ any normative definition in 2003. We can probably rely on the example and on common sense, but..

Comment: @PaulH: your reasoning seems sound, but I don't use `iostreams` much and am not all that knowledgeable about the details of the classes involved. So honestly I wouldn't count on what I might think...  But, if you let the `ostream` base default construct, then call `rdbuf( static_cast<MyStreamBuf*>(this))` inside the constructor, I think there will be no questions about the stability of the `this` pointer for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

It's warning you about the use of `this` in the initializer list because technically, `this` doesn't exist yet because the constructor hasn't finished executing yet (nor have the constructors of any member objects) and passing it to a function could cause problems when they try to use that object (which contains objects whose constructors haven't been called).

The code should work if you're just storing the pointer for use later. But when you come back to this code and forget that you're not supposed to use that pointer, you might make a mistake and not be able to explain why your program is crashing.

Here is the Microsoft page for that warning: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c594ae3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, this only happens when you explicitly use `this` in the mem-initializer list. Passing the address of a member variable that has not yet been constructed does not raise C4355.

Take a look at `fstream`'s constructor if you need proof.